# Does htmlunit creates browser instances on the machine where it is running?

Tags: selenium, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit for web scraping - logging to a website on behalf of the users, settings something in their profile and then come back.
Just using pure Htmlunit and no selenium framework.
Now my question:
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11);

Does this statement - creates a browser instance on the machine where i am executing the code or what it does?
I am using BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11 as this is an accepted browser at that website.

How Selenium is different than htmlunit - i know we can use htmlunit as a webdriver in Selenium. Does Selenium needs a native browser instance on the machine where the code is getting executed? Does Selenium creates browser instances?

My use case is - I will be having multiple users accessing this application. I know WebClient in htmlunit is not thread safe(so have to code it as Spring proto type bean).
Is there any suggestions regarding this?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLUnit is a headless browser. So no *window* will be created if used with Selenium either. Setting the `BrowserVersion` will just tell HTMLUnit to present itself to the server *as if it were* a given browser (AFAIK, it will just change the User-Agent but might perform additional internal processing depending on the version). I guess this answers most of the questions but the last one.

Regarding asking for suggestions on how to implement this I would try to avoid logging in to a website that way. If the website does not provide an API for this then it is likely that it is agains the Terms Of Service. Assuming it is not, you will have to create new WebClient instances for each user each time the data needs to be extracted from the other site.